# How to get spinner selected item in android?

Tags: java, android

I am making a currency converter with two spinners. I want to make an "if" function using the values of the spinner's selected item like below.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (spinner1.getSelectedItem()=="Dollars" && spinner2.getSelectedItem()=="Euros") {
        convertDollarstoEuros();
    }
    if (spinner1.getSelectedItem()=="Euros" && spinner2.getSelectedItem()=="Euros") {
        convertEurostoEuros();
    }
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        "OnClickListener : " + 
                "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + 
                "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The problem is that the toast is showing, but the currencies aren't converting. The toast part is working, but the spinner part isn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my LogCat:

http://oi39.tinypic.com/2n7i63o.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Use the OnItemSelectedListener on your Spinner

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            String text = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("Dollars")) {

                //do something
                            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to get the position of both of the spinners.  Isn't this the listener for only one spinner?  What should I do?

Comment: firstly, why do you need two spinners? A spinner is similar to a combo box where you select a item from the dropdown and do something for that

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing String directly. In Java, you should be comparing Strings with the `equals` method.

```
if("Dollars".equals(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) && ...
```

See the following question for more detail: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: if crashes, check the errors in the logcat